# Creating Class Instances Dynamically in Python

Tags: python, csv

How can I generate class instances dynamically? Specifically, what I'm looking to do:

I'm pulling in data from a spreadsheet, which gets converted to CSV. The row is the header. After the header row, each row represents data about a particular order (col1 is the order ID, col2 is the customer name, col 3 is the date, col 4 is the quantity, etc.). Right now, I'm importing the CSV to a list of dictionaries. So each item in the list stores a dictionary that pulls the key from the header row. So, I could lookup the quantity of order #5 by:

```
orderDict[5]['quantity']
```

I'm very new to object-oriented programming... but would like to make each of these orders an instance of the Order class. So, I'd like to create a class called "Order" then have it pull the properties from the header row of the CSV. So, something like (inputList is the list that was pulled in from the CSV file):

```
class Order(object):
        """Defines an individual order"""
        def __init__(self, inputList):
            for z in range(len(inputList[0]))
                self.inputList[0][z] = None
```

I'd then like to have some code that goes through the data imported from the CSV and creates an instance for each row.

```
for a in range(len(inputList))
    if a != 0:
        orderName = 'order%d' % (a)
        orderName = Order() #I know this won't work... but not sure how I variably name this
        for b in range(len(inputList[a]))
            orderName.b = inputList[a][b]
```

The result would be an instance called order1, order2, order3, order4, etc. The number of instances created would be dependent on the number of rows in the original data. Could be 4... could be thousands.

This way, if I want to find the quantity of order 5, I can just call for:

```
order5.quantity
```

However, so far it appears that I would need to explicitly create each instance manually:

```
order1 = Order()
order2 = Order()
order3 = Order()
```

Not very convenient or dynamic when dealing with thousands of orders (and growing). Seems like there should be a way to dynamically generate these instances based on the data being fed into the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the instances to have global variable names (e.g. order1, order2, etc) it is possible (but very ugly) using e.g. `globals()['order' + num] = Order(...)`. The far cleaner and safer way would be to store the instances in a single dict. Also for the sake of efficiency, you could pop the header to avoid the test for zero from each iteration, could use xrange instead of range to avoid slurping complete sets of data around, could optionally set the attributes in the object's init rather than afterwards (seeing the info is already available...), and could pass only the header and line to each instantiation rather than all the data. By the way there are colons missing from the ends of your for-lines:

```
class Order(object):
    """Defines an individual order"""
    def __init__(self, input_header, input_line):
        for z in xrange(len(input_header)):
            setattr(self, input_header[z], input_line[z])

orders = {}
input_header = input_list.pop(0)
for a in xrange(len(input_list)):
    orders[a] = Order(input_header, input_list[a])
```

Answer (score 1):

the general solution to this is to use a dictionary mapping strings to classes

```
classes = {"order":Order,"something":Something}

keys = ["order","order","something"]
my_instances = [classes[key]() for key in keys]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add the appropriate attributes to an instance of the order class during after its instantiation like so:

```
class Order(object):
    def __init__(self,pairs):
        for k,v in pairs:
            setattr(self,k,v)
    def __str__(self):
        return "oID: %s, custName: %s, Date: %s, Qty %s" %(self.orderID,self.custName,self.Date,self.Qty)
```

This will take in an iterable which contains `(key,value)` tuples. It will then add attributes based on the `key` and `value`.

Using this class we can create orders from a csv file like so:

```
orderID,custName,Date,Qty
1,Bob,2/3/2013,2
2,jane,2/4/2013,1
```

Using the `DictReader` class from the csv module:

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('orders.csv') as f:
    orders = []
    reader = DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        orders.append(Order(row.items()))
```

Which will result in:

```
for order in orders:
    print(order)
>>> 
oID: 1, custName: Bob, Date: 2/3/2013, Qty 2
oID: 2, custName: jane, Date: 2/4/2013, Qty 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating classes with dynamic properties and dynamic variable names is probably a not a good idea. How will your program know what they are in order to access them? For example:

```
 order5.quantity
```

assumes that there was at least 5 (or 6) orders and that Orders have a `quantity` attribute.

Generating class attribute names from CSV file header field names is problematic because they might not be valid Python identifiers.

Although this doesn't address the last issue, you should consider something like the following instead:

Given a sample file, `orders.csv`, like this:

```
order_id,customer,date,product,quantity
01,Brian,2013-12-01,Spam,2
13,Eric,2013-11-28,Eggs,3
42,John,2013-11-30,Cheese,4
```

You could use something like the following:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv

class Orders(object):
    def __init__(self, csv_filename):
        with open(csv_filename, 'rb') as inputfile:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
            self.fields = csv_reader.next()  # read header row
            self.Order = namedtuple('Order', self.fields)
            self.records = [self.Order(*row) for row in csv_reader]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.records[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.records)
```

Which would allow most of the sort of usage you desire:

```
orders = Orders('orders.csv')

if len(orders) >= 3:
    print orders[2].quantity  # assumes name of a field

for id, order in enumerate(orders):
    print 'order id {}: {}'.format(id, order)
```

Output:

```
 4
 order id 0: Order(order_id='01', customer='Brian', date='2013-12-01', product='Spam', quantity='2')
 order id 1: Order(order_id='13', customer='Eric', date='2013-11-28', product='Eggs', quantity='3')
 order id 2: Order(order_id='42', customer='John', date='2013-11-30', product='Cheese', quantity='4')
```